# Bootstrap Multiselect - Dynamic option population

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, wicket, bootstrap-multiselect

I am using [Bootstrap Multiselect](http://davidstutz.github.io/bootstrap-multiselect/) for my application requirements. My application also uses wicket framework. I am facing an issue refreshing one of the bootstrap multiselect in my app. Please refer image below

[image]

Based on the value chosen from *Report Area* select box, *Available* multiselect should refresh with appropriate options. While the underlying regular multiselect is modified with different values, boostrap multiselect which sits on top of it is unable to refresh.

*Report Area* select box is using wicketajax and I have tried below code to refresh *Available* bootstrap multiselect

```
<div>Report Area:</div>
<div>
    <select wicket:id="reportArea">
        <option value="TaskCardAssignment">TaskCardAssignment</option>                                                           
    </select>
</div>
<div class="labelbg">Available:</div>
<div class="select">
    <select wicket:id="available" multiple="true" size="15">
       <option value="Workgroup">Workgroup</option>                                                      
    </select>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var idAvailable = jQuery('[name="attributes:available"]').attr('id');
    var availbleId = jQuery('#'+idAvailable);
    availbleId.multiselect(); //Creates multiselect 

    jQuery('[name="attributes:reportArea"]').change(function(e) {
      setTimeout(function() {
            availbleId.multiselect('rebuild');
            availbleId.multiselect('refresh');
        },0);
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Are you refreshing the `select` with Wicket's ajax?

Comment: Yes @WiseTree. Available multiselect gets refreshed based on reportArea select value change through wicket. reportArea Select code:
    <select name="attributes:reportArea" id="reportArea" onchange="var wcall=wicketAjaxPost('createApp?18-1.IBehaviorListener.0-report-attributes-reportArea', wicketSerialize(Wicket.$('reportArea')),function() { }.bind(this),function() { }.bind(this), function() {return Wicket.$('reportArea') != null;}.bind(this));">
 <option selected="selected" value="">Choose One</option>
 <option value="one">One</option>
 <option value="two">Two</option>
</select>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wicket's Ajax and Bootstrap Multiselect don't work very well together.

When you create the multiselect via the `availbleId.multiselect();` call, the bootstrap multiselect attaches some data to the dom element of the original select (can't quite recall exactly what the data was). From my investigations into a similar issue this data appears to be crucial to correct functionality of Bootstrap Multiselect.

Wicket's Ajax, however, has other plans. When you re-render a component via wicket's ajax, what wicket does is it re-renders the HTML for the component (and any scripts that might be relevant) and sends the new html to the client. On the browser side, wicket **completely replaces** the old DOM element with a new one containing newly generated HTML.

You can probably guess what the issue is by now. When wicket replaces the HTML for the original select, any data that Bootstrap Multiselect has attached to the DOM element is gone. This causes the multiselect to stop working.

Unfortunately there is no easy solution to this problem. Unlike things like `ListView` where individual options within are also wicket components, the options in any component extending `AbstractChoice` are not, and hence cannot be individually re-rendered. However, one solution you could use is that instead of re-rendering your `AbstractChoice`, you could generate the HTML for the options and write some javascript to only replace the options and not the select itself. This could be done by doing basically the same thing as wicket does in [`AbstractChoice#onComponentTagBody()`](https://ci.apache.org/projects/wicket/apidocs/7.x/org/apache/wicket/markup/html/form/AbstractChoice.html#onComponentTagBody(org.apache.wicket.markup.MarkupStream,%20org.apache.wicket.markup.ComponentTag)). That is, instead of doing

```
@Override 
protected void onUpdate(final AjaxRequestTarget target) { 
    target.add(availableFields);
}
```

You could do something like

```
@Override 
protected void onUpdate(final AjaxRequestTarget target) { 

    // Generate HTML for the select's options - this is literally the code from AbstractChoice#onComponentTagBody()

    List<? extends T> choices = getChoices();
    final AppendingStringBuffer buffer = new AppendingStringBuffer((choices.size() * 50) + 16);
    final String selectedValue = getValue();

    buffer.append(getDefaultChoice(selectedValue));

    for (int index = 0; index < choices.size(); index++)
    {
        final T choice = choices.get(index);
        appendOptionHtml(buffer, choice, index, selectedValue);
    }

    // Create javascript which will replace the body of the select with the new options
    String replacementJavaScript =
            "$('#" + this.getMarkupId() + "')" +
                    ".replaceWith('" + buffer.toString().replace("'", "\"") + "');";

    String multiselectRefresh = "$(yourMultiselectSelector).multiselect('refresh');"

    target.appendJavaScript(replacementJavaScript + multiselectRefresh);
}
```

Comment: Thats a good information you have given @WiseTree. I will apply your suggestion and then update here what works. Thq

Comment: Btw @WiseTree, I forgot to update that I am getting values in to Bootstrap Multiselect when i do the following with the code mentioned in the question area - 

1. Choose a value from ReportArea single select box.
2. No value population occurs in Available MultiSelect box.
3. Manually refresh the browser, there i see values populated..

Comment: That's expected as really the only part of the process that fails is the multiselect display. If you would inspect the HTML you would see a hidden `<select>` component with the new values included as well.

Comment: Yes, I do see that hidden `<select>` was reloaded with new components. From UI, if i can wait until wicket ajax completes its work, i.e. refreshing hidden select and then apply the code for bootstrap multiselect conversion, it may work. I am just looking for that code as `.isajaxstop` etc methods are not working

Comment: [`AjaxRequestTarget#appendJavaScript()`](https://ci.apache.org/projects/wicket/apidocs/7.x/org/apache/wicket/core/request/handler/IPartialPageRequestHandler.html#appendJavaScript(java.lang.CharSequence)) might be useful for that

Comment: Excellent. Now, options are updated, but, getting new multiselect each time report area option changes.
`String availableJS = "var idAvailable = jQuery('[name=\"attributes:available\"]').attr('id');\n"+ "var availbleId = jQuery('#'+idAvailable);\n"
                 + "availbleId.multiselect('rebuild');\n"
                 + "availbleId.multiselect('refresh');\n";
            @Override
            protected void onUpdate(final AjaxRequestTarget target)
            {
                target.add(availableFields);
                target.appendJavaScript(availableJS);
            }`

Comment: Thing is, as long as you use `target.add(availableFields);`, the multiselect is going to break and be unrefreshable due to the original DOM select being replaced with a new one; the solution needs to replace only the options and not the select itself, which you can't do with wicket ajax. I edited the answer to show an example fix.

Comment: OK, got the expected result by using below code
              `target.prependJavaScript(availableJSPre);
                target.add(availableFields);
                target.appendJavaScript(availableJSApp);'
availableJSPre - JS code to destroy multiselect
availableJSApp - Reinitialize multiselect

Thanks @WiseTree. Your code helped and i will mark it accepted answer